# s2:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()

Tags: node.js, arrays

Bonjour à tous j'aimerai resoudre ce probleme voici l'erreur que j'ai rencontré au niveau de la consolerning: Failed prop type: MUI: The `anchorEl` prop provided to the component is invalid.
It should be an Element instance but it's

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.